# Defining axes for conservation of energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy-conservation, conventions

Problem: A bungee-cord jumper is on a bridge that is $y_1$ above water level $y_2$.
The bungee cord obeys Hooke's law with spring constant $k$ and has a relaxed length $L$
The jumper stops before reaching the water, what height is her feet above the water at this point $d$?

> I define the positive y direction as up and $y_2=0$.

From this definition and given that the initial energy is

$$E_i=mgy_1\tag{1}$$

I reason $\Delta h$ should be $y_1$ by a separate isolated case where a mass has $E_g =mgh$, when it is distance $h$ above a given 0 reference point.

The final energy is a combination of $U_s=\frac{1}{2}kx^2$ and remaining $U_g=mgd$.

Remembering the defined positive y direction, $d$ is positive by the same reasoning as for $y_1$. $x$ would be negative but can be ignored due to the even power.

$g$ would be negative.

The total initial energy in the system will be equivalent to the total final energy in the system given no non conservative forces apply. However, setting $E_i = E_f$ and solving for x to calculate the required $d$,

$$\frac{1}{2}kx^2 - mgx - mgL=0\tag{2}$$

Yields a quadratic equation with no real solutions (as $g$ is negative). It is clear that my **interpretation** of my defined axes is incorrect.

The problem is provided for situational awareness only, my question is given the convention I have used, why should $E_i=mg\Delta h$ be $mg(y_2-y_1)$ (a negative value as opposed to $y_1$).

If this is the case wouldn't that also mean that $d$ should be negative and so the quadratic would still have no real solutions?

Comment: In eqn (2) $g$ should be entered as a positive number not a negative number. Do that and you'll get the correct answer. The reason is that in eqn (1) the energy change is $mg(y_{final}−y_{initial})$ and $y_{final}-y_{initial}$ is a negative number because you′re moving downwards. However you've put in the positive number $y_1$ instead, which means you′re using the convention that down is positive. With this convention $g$ is positive as well.

Comment: Nic, I answered in a comment because your question is very likely to be closed as a [homework question](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange). You may wish to delete the question to avoid downvotes.

Comment: I have reworded the question, I believe it now meets the criteria of a homework question: [link](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange). Upon second look at $mg(y_{final}-y_{initial})$ I thought that if y is defined as down (making $g$ positive) that this would then make my $y_{initial}$ zero and $y_{final}$ negative. I think my problem is that I was equating initial and final energy directly without considering work involved. I will try again after re-reading the work energy theorm.